# The resize() function doesn't resize my image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, customtkinter

```
imageopen = Image.open("logo.png")
imageopen = imageopen.resize((1000,1000), Image.LANCZOS)

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand="True")

image = ctk.CTkImage(imageopen)
label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=image, text="", height=200)
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
```

So while I'm working on a UI using customtkinter, I added a label which contains the image "logo.png". But when I run the code, the image is extremely small. So I tried to resize it with Pillow's resize() function but is does not work. This is my code, but the image is still very small.

I have tried change "LANCZOS" in to "ANTIALIAS" but it does not work

Comment: Try adding `print(imageopen)` immediately before and again immediately after the line `imageopen = imageopen.resize((1000,1000), Image.LANCZOS)`

Answer (score 0):

You could install the Pillow library (pip install Pillow) to do this

Exmaple:

```
 from PIL import Image
 imageopen = Image.open("logo.png")
 resized_image = imageopen.resize((1000, 1000), Image.LANCZOS)
 # Now you can use the resized image in your UI
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the `size` in `CTKImage`.

[See CTkImage Documentation](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/utility-classes/image).

Here is the updated functional code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import customtkinter as ctk

imageopen = Image.open("logo.png")
size = (1000, 1000) #Size you need

root = ctk.CTk()

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand="True")

image = ctk.CTkImage(imageopen, size=size) # Specify size here
label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=image, text="", height=200)
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tysm! it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The image filter modes BICUBIC, ANTIALIAS and Resampling.LANCZOS are more or less the same. That is ANTIALIAS was deprecated and BICUBIC was introduced. The difference between BICUBIC and Resampling.LANCZOS is very little. Also Resampling.LANCZOS doesn't work in all the versions of PIL module. Also it is said that when PIL module is used as a dependency in another module, Resampling.LANCZOS doesn't work. As the default filter mode is BICUBIC, you don't need to mention the filter mode. So, the following will work.

```
import PIL.Image as Image
imageopen = Image.open("logo.png")
imageopen = imageopen.resize((1000,1000))

frame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand="True")

image = ctk.CTkImage(imageopen)
label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame, image=image, text="", height=200)
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
```